# RecognitionListener: OnPartialResults vs OnResults

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

In terms of performance and usability, what is the best approach? What are the main differences between these two methods?

I currently have an implementation on "OnResults" that is constantly listening and compares with a couple strings, taking distinct actions for each word detected. However, it fails on recognizing the words some times and sometimes doesn't even listen to anything. If I moved the logic to "OnPartialResults" would improve the usability?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`onResults` is called when SpeechRecognizer finishes listening.
`onPartialResults` is called when SpeechRecognizer detect new word you have spoken, even before end of listening.

Both of them should have got the same results for single spoken words, but if your speech is longer, `onResults` can modify your output to make it little more grammatically correct (but just little bit).

Usage of them depends of your purposes. But more accuratrate results are given with `onResults`.

If you want to match spoken words to action, create own matcher, which would choose the best matching (but not always equal, because it does not work always).

More about [onResults](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onResults(android.os.Bundle)) and [onPartialResults](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onPartialResults(android.os.Bundle)) at developer.android.com

Important: to get partial results, you have to add extra to recognizer intent:

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
```

Comment: Additionaly to call most accurate event while matching spoken words to events, for example you can count distance between two strings counting [Jaro–Winkler distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) from StringUtils in org.apache.commons.lang3

Comment: I've used that before. Could work nicely here, didn't think of that. Thanks again!